# Google Drive API Query by Name Returns Invalid

Tags: google-drive-api

1. According to Google Drive documentation, to query for a file by name you would use: q="name = 'file name'".

   https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters
2. When I try to search by name here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it

   Setting the "q" field to "name = 'file_name'".

   "The value of the parameter 'q' is invalid." is returned.
3. The same thing happens when I try to execute the command in Python:\

   `service.files().list(q="name = 'file_name'").execute()`
4. Other commands like q="trashed=false" work fine. Not sure why "name" queries do not.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you are attempting to use search parameters defined specifically for the [Drive v3 API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/) with the [Drive v2 API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/).

When using the [Drive v2 API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/), the name of the file is found under 'title', so a valid query is:

title = 'TestDoc'

Whereas in [Drive v3 API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/), the name of the file is found under 'name':

name = 'TestDoc'

Comment: thanks! ==> title = 'TestDoc'