# List of folder not shared with me, Google Drive API

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

In my application, I want to list all folder that exist in my drive, but I don't know how to do it. I want to list folder just in "My Drive" not in "Shared with me".

Here is my code :

```
 Dim fold = Service.Files.List()
       fold.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'  and trashed = false and 'me' in owners "
```

But I have an exception: `Invalid Query [400]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list).

Also, the `includeTeamDriveItems` was already set to **false** as a default value. From here, you will be able to set if you want to include team drives in the result.

Try the code from the quickstart.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DriveQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = {  DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Drive API service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

            // Define parameters of request.
            FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
            listRequest.PageSize = 10;
            listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

            // List files.
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
                .Files;
            Console.WriteLine("Files:");
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Regarding your error, I think you are trying to use search parameters specific for two different versions, [Drive v3 API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/) and [Drive v2 API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)

You can refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735220/google-drive-api-query-by-name-returns-invalid) for further information.

Comment: Thank you for your help , i just add " 'me' in owners " in  fold.Q instruction ...