# Using 'name contains' to query a Team Drive with Google Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm making a request to find all files belonging to a certain client in a Team Drive.

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293530/browse-files-in-google-team-drive), this is the code:

```
function listFiles (){
  var client = 'client'
  var teamDriveId = 'id';
  var pageToken;
  var folders = Drive.Files.list({  
    corpora: 'teamDrive',
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
    teamDriveId: teamDriveId,
    includeTeamDriveItems: true,
    q: "title = 'data'"
  });
  if (folders.items.length !== 1) {
    Logger.log('There is a problem.');
    return;
  }
  var query = "name contains '" + client + // this client only
    "' and trashed = false and " + // not in trash 
    "not mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"; // no folders
  Logger.log(query)
  var files, pageToken;
  do {
    files = Drive.Files.list({
      q: query,
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken,
      // required for team drive queries
      corpora: 'teamDrive',
      supportsTeamDrives: true,
      teamDriveId: teamDriveId,
      includeTeamDriveItems: true
    });
    if (files.items && files.items.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < files.items.length; i++) {
        var file = files.items[i];
        Logger.log('%s (ID: %s) (Modified: %s)', file.title, file.id, file.modifiedDate);
        }        
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No files found.');
    }
    pageToken = files.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

If I do not include the `"name contains '" + client'"` portion of the query, it works fine. If I do, it returns an error stating just: "Invalid query".

Looking at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters), I'm not understand how my syntax differs from the what is specified there.

I've tried multiple variations along these lines:

- `"name contains 'client' and trashed = false and not mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"`
- `"trashed = false and not mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name contains 'client'"`

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: V2 uses `title` not `name` for the file property that stores the filename

Comment: Can't believe I missed that  Submit it as an answer, it solved the problem

Comment: I should have just flagged this as a duplicate (rather than to close as typo): https://stackoverflow.com/q/34735220/9337071